# Windows Update (sorta) bricked my computer. Now I want my settings back

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, windows.old

After the most recent Windows Update, I saw this screen. Clicking the button, the computer restarted, and returned to this screen.

[image: I hate Windows.]

So then I burnt a copy of Windows and reinstalled it:

[image]

But that wasn't any more useful. I started to saw consistent blue screens of death. But at least they included a stop code: VIDEO DXGKRNL FATAL ERROR.

So I removed my dual video cards and plugged it into the onboard slot. That seems to have resolved the issue.

I now have two new directories:

- c:\windows.old (1/26/2018, the date of the Windows Update)
- c:\windows.old.000 (1/28/2018, today's date)

Now that I've figured out what's wrong, I'd MUCH prefer to go back (if not completely, then partially) to the Windows instance/settings I had before I reinstalled.

I don't have any checkpoints.

Surprisingly, I'm almost out of drive space, 3.29 GB free out of 238 GB.

Comment: You will be unable to revert your actions if you installed Windows within WinPE

Comment: Can I use the /windows.old or /windows.old.000 directories to restore some aspects of my configuration?

Comment: You can restore the files but the configuration itself (i.e. installed programs) are pretty much lost.  Your users are also lost.

Comment: ok. Please create an answer to that effect and I'll accept it.